# Node.js MongoDB .findOne returns best match when querying a String

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

If I create a document in MongoDB using the create method.

```
Ua.create({myStringField: 'myStringData'}, function(err, myUa){
  callback(err,myUa);
});
```

Later I then want to search for a new string in the database and use this method.

```
Ua.findOne({myStringField: 'myStringDataNEW'}, function(err, myUa){
  callback(err,myUa);
});
```

Notice that I set the original myStringField with data 'myStringData' and am now searching for 'myStringDataNEW'.  The findOne() method returns the document containing 'myStringData' as the result of this query.

How do I query only for exact matches to strings in MongoDB?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't have the answer right now, but note that you can use `Ua.create({...}, callback);` directly instead of creating an intermediary function.

Comment: Pikrass, thanks for the note, understood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty certain you are getting confused. Your `findOne` call will do an exact, case-sensitive match. To do partial matches or case-insensitive you need to use a `RegExp` instance not a basic string. My suggestion is to make a simple test case separate from your app, and my suspicion is the DB is not behaving the way you think it is.

Comment: Yes, this has been driving me a little insane.  I've just tested direct through the MongoDB console and it's returning as you describe, however using Mongoose is returning as I've described.  Thanks for coming back so quickly, I'll create a reduce test case a little later and report back.

Comment: you are correct, the exact issue I had was running Mocha tests against some code where I'd forgotten to include an else statement around a return callback, so the test had fallen through and become asynchronous before my code had returned from the findOne() statement. Your answer helped my diagnose this, so thank you very much.